# Mouse click vs viewer.select function selection behave differently in Autodesk Forge multi models viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have been working on multi-model from the last couple of weeks and found that selection of a model object using mouse click vs viewer select function behave differently.

I have two models one architectural and another mechanical. When I select a wall or room on the architectural model using mouse click, Object select with overlay without having any problem but when I try using viewer select function with same object, it hides behind the wall and overlay doesn't work. It is only happening with the architectural model and working fine with the mechanical model.

Please suggest me if I am doing something wrong with multi-model.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically select components when working with multiple models use `viewer.select(dbid, model)`:

```
let model = viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels()[index] or viewer.impl.findModel(modelId);
viewer.select(dbid, model)
```

And to get selected dbids use `viewer.getAggregateSelection` (see doc [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.html#select)) the event to subscribe to `AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT` (doc [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.html#event:AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT)) to track selection changes:

If the issue persists can you send some screenshots and your models (links via a sharing service like weTransfer/Dropbox) for further investigation over to forge.help@autodesk.com?

Comment: Thanks Bryan for your response. I am doing the same which have suggested in your response. I am going to send an email to forge.help@autodesk.com with screenshots.